# overlapping images using GDI+

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gdi+

I'm trying to write a webApplication that holds two png images- big one and smaller one,
I need to use the bigger one as a base and place the smaller one on it in a specific posiotion, the smaller one has transparent areas so it adds information to the base picture.

I'm using GDI+ with C#, but I managed only to upload one picture (the base one) using the following code:
Bitmap objImage = new Bitmap("basePngPicturePath");
objImage.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
objImage.Dispose();

I could,'t use two pictures- it doesn't work...
and this was the only way I managed to upload a picture.
HELP PLEASE!!! 
I really need this to work...

Answer (score 5):

You could draw the smaller image onto the larger one before the page is rendered, with code something like this:

```
Bitmap objImage = new Bitmap("basePngPicturePath");
Bitmap objSmallImage = new Bitmap("smallPngPicturePath");
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(objImage))
{
    g.DrawImage(...); // there are 30-some overloads of DrawImage, but 
        // basically you use objSmallImage as the source, 
        // plus various ways of telling the method
        // where to draw the smaller image.
}
objImage.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
objImage.Dispose();
objSmallImage.Dispose();
```

Comment: Obligatory remark about the need to handle objSmallImage and objImage through _using blocks_ as well. Especially in a Web app. +1 for the rest.

Comment: Hi, thsnks for the quick reply,
I tried your code but it only drew the smaller picture.
I even tried to add a line before the line that draw the small picture another that draw the base one- but it still shows only the small picture. (I used g.DrawImage(objSmallImage,new Point(10,10);

Comment: @Henk: baby steps, dude. I was trying to fit the code into the original asker's code. Besides, calling Dispose on both bitmaps accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: @aye: not sure why you'd get that result. Try changing the first two lines to Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromFile([filepathontheserver]) to make sure you're actually loading the saved images into the bitmaps.